# Initiate downloads with a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have multiple URLs for users to download. The download should be triggered after they hit "Like" or post a "Tweet". I have successfully setup the callback functions for both.

I wish to know how do I employ Javascript so that the multiple downloads are triggered simultaneously. One solution would be to use `window.location`, but that would trigger just single download. I can even do multiple `window.open` but the pop-up blocker would block this.

What other alternatives do I have for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a hidden iframe with the src of the file for each download, something like:

```
function download(url){ 
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
  iframe.src = url;
  iframe.style.display = "none"; 
  document.body.appendChild(iframe); 
}
```

Comment: This, with multiple calls, doesn't seem to be working in Chrome.

Comment: mmm... I just tested it with a for with 10 calls and it works... inspecting with chrome dev tools, all requests are sent at the same time...

Comment: There are no downloads prompts in Chrome, instead this gets logged in console `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/[zip/pdf/...]`

Comment: can you try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vHwzu/ there is a problem with PDFs or images to download, since they are "opened" in the invisible iframe, but zips (even though the console shows an error I got them downloaded)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function if you need to make the browser download files without using `content-disposition: attachment;filename=filename` header.

```
function aDownload( url, name ) {
    // Original code from https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
    // Rewrited to work without blobs
    // Will return true if worked
    var click, save_link, event;
    save_link = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a")
    if( !("download" in save_link) ) return false; // a[download] not supported on this browser
    save_link.href = url;
    save_link.download = name;
    event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initMouseEvent(
        "click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        , false, false, false, false, 0, null
    );
    return save_link.dispatchEvent(event); // false if event was cancelled
}
```