# How to download some images of a website directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

For example, I want to download images from ID 663500 to 665000 :

From this one
http://geo.static.traxsource.com/files/images/663500_large.jpg
To
http://geo.static.traxsource.com/files/images/665000_large.jpg

How should I do it?

Comment: Use your mouse, point to the image you want to download. Now right click that image, and in the menu that pops up select "save as" or something similar. Chose where to save the image, and you're done.

Comment: I think what he wants is batch download

Comment: @iWillGetBetter - then (s)he should explain better what the issue is, what language (s)he's using, what's been tried etc.

Comment: Based on the tags I think he has no idea how to do it. And youre right, he should explain what has been tried.

Comment: If you just want a tool, have a look at urltoys. It allows you to write eg `fusk http://geo.static.traxsource.com/files/images/6[63500-66500]_large.jpg ` and then `get` these files. Programmatically it should just be a for loop.

Comment: Do you want to do it with javascript or php?

Comment: From my understanding he wants to override the other image.

Comment: You solve it by programming. If you show use what you have tried so far we can help you fix your problems. This is not a service where you can ask for something on a silver plate.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little script for you. This way every second a new file gets downloaded.

```js
var url = "http://geo.static.traxsource.com/files/images/{num}_large.jpg";
var startnum = 663500;
var endnum = 665000;
var interval = 1 * 1000; //in MS

function downloadNext(num) {
  if (num < endnum) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      downloadNext(num + 1);
    }, interval)
  }
  var downUrl = url.replace("{num}", num);
  aDownload(downUrl, num + "_large.jpg");
}

downloadNext(startnum);

//CREDITS TO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900289/initiate-downloads-with-a-javascript-function
function aDownload(url, name) {
  // Original code from https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
  // Rewrited to work without blobs
  // Will return true if worked
  var click, save_link, event;
  save_link = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a")
  if (!("download" in save_link)) return false; // a[download] not supported on this browser
  save_link.href = url;
  save_link.download = name;
  event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  event.initMouseEvent(
    "click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null
  );
  return save_link.dispatchEvent(event); // false if event was cancelled
}
```

Comment: horrible... multiple download dialogs, skips downloads since chrome can only show one at the time

Comment: @Endless Could be better indeed, but is sufficient for this user.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// using JSZip to save a bunch of stuff
var zip = new JSZip
var from = 663500
var to = 663510
// requires cors headers...
var corsProxy = 'https://crossorigin.me/'
var src = corsProxy + 'http://geo.static.traxsource.com/files/images/'

// append a bunch of file we want to download
for (; from < to; from++) {
  let name = from + '_large.jpg'
  let url = src + name
  zip.file(name, fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()))
}

// generate the zip content
zip.generateAsync({
  type: 'blob'
})
// download using FileSaver.js
.then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'example.zip'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```